# How do I get list of attachment from Opportunity into Account?

Tags: apex

```
public with sharing class DisplayProfilePictureController{

    public Attachment file{set;get;}
    public Boolean hasPicture{set;get;}
    private String parentId{set;get;}
    List<Id> accountIds= new List<Id>();
    public List<Attachment> attList{get;set;}
    List<Account> accounts=new List<Account>();
    List<Opportunity> opps=new List<Opportunity>();

    public DisplayProfilePictureController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.parentId = stdController.getId();
    System.debug('&&&&'+parentId);
    this.hasPicture = false;
    accounts=[Select Id,name,(select Id,name from opportunities) from account       
    where Id in:accountIds];
    attList = [SELECT ParentId, Name, Id, ContentType, BodyLength FROM Attachment 
                                        WHERE ParentId =: this.ParentId];
    }


}
```

In the above code i am getting the list of attachment from Account as parent.Now i want to get list of attachment of child of account i.e opportunity

Comment: Hi karuna and welcome to SFSE. It is a good practice to explain your problem and where are you stuck, expected outcome and what happens now. Posting only a block of code will most probably get this question closed as "Too low quality" or "Unclear what you are asking". Consider editing your question and adding some details

Comment: In the above code i am getting the list of attachment from Account as parent.Now i want to get list of attachment of child of account i.e opportunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pull attachments from all opportunities of a single account then you can do -

For single account -

```
attList = [SELECT ParentId,Name,Id,ContentType,BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId in (Select Id from opportunity where accountId=:this.ParentId)];
```

For multiple account (do remember the SOQL max. rows governor limit)

```
  attList = [SELECT ParentId,Name,Id,ContentType,BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId in (Select Id from opportunity where accountId in :this.AccountIds)];
```